# How can I read the value of a field in Firestore (Swift)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I want to read out the Value of an Field of my document (in Firebase Firestore with SwiftUI).
What I already have I this:

```
 let value = myDataBase
 // My Database instance
 //
 value.collection("My Collection").whereField("Code", isEqualTo: codeTextInput)
     .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
         if let err = err {
             print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
         } else {
             for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                 print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                                    
             }
        }
   }
```

(This Code works fine)

And now I want to store the Value of all Documents, which are in my collection and have for the key "Code" the value, which is typed in. But I want to store the Data for the key "Wert"

[image: This is the Firebase Backend]

When I've saved it, I want to use it as an User-Default...
Btw. I don’t want collect more then 1 item with this code, I just want that this item which I collect is the right.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit (in your question) what you want to do with the values? Do you want to aggregate them (e.g. sum them up), display them in a list, ...?

Comment: It’s done. I just wanna say: I don’t want to collect more than one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let sum it up:

1. You want all documents in your collection with a certain value to be fetched
2. You want to save all of these values and be able to access them.

I can only recommend working with `objects` in this scenario. Let's make an example:

Lets import all modules

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import FirebaseStorage
import Combine
```

First we declare the structure:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#custom_objects

```
public struct MyObject: Codable {

    let id: String
    let code: String?

    // Needed to identify them in Firestore
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case code = "code"
    }

}
```

Now we access it and generate an Object for each document we can fetch that contains your desired value:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#custom_objects

```
var myArray: Array<MyObject> = [] // Empty array where we will store all objects in
var codeTextInput = "Test"

// Fetch only desired documents
let db = Firestore.firestore()
let docRef = db.collection("My Collection").whereField("Code", isEqualTo: codeTextInput)

func getDocumentsAsObjects() { // docRef.getDocuments Needs to be in function or else: Expressions are not allowed at the top level
    docRef.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in //getDocuments (s) as in multiple 
        
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents { // iterate them and add them to your array
                let result = Result {
                    try document.data(as: MyObject.self)
                }
                
                switch result {
                case .success(let myObject):
                    if let myObject = myObject {
                        myObject.id = document!.documentID // Get the ID of the Document as we might need it later
                        myArray.append(myObject) // Save the document into your array
                    } else {
                        // A nil value was successfully initialized from the DocumentSnapshot,
                        // or the DocumentSnapshot was nil.
                        print("Document does not exist")
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    // A `MyObject` value could not be initialized from the DocumentSnapshot.
                    print("Error decoding city: \(error)")
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you have your Objects in your array and can access them

Comment: When I do I like this I get the error: Value of type 'Query' has no member 'getDocument'

Comment: You are right. I didn't check for it to compile. Bad answer from me. Is corrected now and compiles for me.

Comment: Just a quick note - as all your field names match the names in the document, there is no need to use `CodingKeys`. You should also use @DocumentID to map the document ID, which will allow you to get rid of the force unwrapping the document ID (`myObject.id = document!.documentID`).

Comment: @Boothosh, does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes you are right. I just kept the CodingKeys from the example and because I assumed he will have more than just 1 value in his document.